# Symfony2 connecting to database via SSH tunneling?

Tags: mysql, symfony, ssh, tunneling

How can I connect to a remote database via SSH tunneling in Symfony2?

I've found the PHP snippet, but how can I integrate it in Symfony

```
<?php
   $smysql = mysql_connect( "127.0.0.1:3307", "dbuser", "PASS" );
   mysql_select_db( "db", $smysql ); 
?>
```

Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

In your parameters.yml file change the `database_port`

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     3307
    database_name:     ...
    database_user:     ...
    database_password: ...
```

This will work when the ssh tunnel exists. Otherwise you'll get a connection error.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to setup an SSH tunnel on your local port 3307 first.

If you're on windows you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.ytechie.com/2008/05/set-up-a-windows-ssh-tunnel-in-10-minutes-or-less/)